# ssh gives an illegal user error

Tags: sshd

Setup a new server and was able to ssh in successfully until I updated apache and php, which maybe upgraded sshd?

`# grep -i allow /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v "^\($\|#\)"
AllowUser lbutlr
AllowGroup wheel
 # groups lbutlr
lbutlr wheel`

When trying to login, the console shows:

`sshd[32444]: error PAM auth error for illegal user lbutlr from 10.1.10.15`

I have stopped sshd and restarted it

Comment: This message indicates that sshd has nothing against the user `lbutlr` but there is no valid account by that name. What does `getent passwd lbutlr` show?

Comment: I can check that when i am at the server, but I can login to the user lbutlr from the console.

Comment: thsnks Giles, I think that did it. The shell was set incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell was set to an invalid path. Using `chsh lbutlr` and setting a valid path fixed the problem. Thanks to Gilles for pointing the way.

Comment: probably not the only thing to look at, but it's a simple one to miss, and it happened to be my problem.

Comment: similar issue. buried in the sshd output was invalid shell. in this case AD/LDAP was providing /bin/zsh which wasn't yet installed on the host. installed it and the error went away. it'd be good if ssh bubbled that simple error up to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

In the config you mention `AllowUser lbutlr` but the error message says `illegal user butler`. May be a mismatch in names causes the error.

Comment: That was an autocorrect failure. The user is lbutlr in all cases.

Comment: Can you edit your question accordingly to be clear.